# Python Script to Search a Folder and Give a List of all Folders and Files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was hoping to use a python script to go through a folder that I have and do the following:

Break the results into multiple columns ex:
Folder name File Name File Path Date Modified Size

I am wanting to create a SQL table based on what is in this folder.

Any tips? I am completely new to Python.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're completely new to Python, you might first try to learn it before attempting such a task.

Comment: ok completely new is an overstatement, I am very new but have used python before but mostly to edit excel documents never in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import sys
import os
import inspect

cwd = os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
print(files)
for i in files:
    print (os.path.abspath(i))
    print (os.path.getmtime(i))
    print (os.path.getsize(i))
```

You need to create database and table.You can read more, [SQLITE](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/create-tables/) about the first steps.Of course you could use MySQL or any other database.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for this, but again totally new to this, when I tried it and swapped the ('.') with my file path I got the below error:
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
did I do something wrong?

Comment: No need to swap it,'.' point to your current directory.Are you on Linux?

Comment: no, sorry I should have mentioned I am on windows and its a networked cloud directory that I am trying to get

Comment: It should work on Windows also.os.path.abspath('.')And you will get.'C:\\Python34'